# Create bmesh & save into OBJ format without opening blender

Tags: python, scripting, command-line, bmesh

I want to create a mesh outside of blender, using `bmesh` module, and save it into an OBJ or whatever, completely through a python script.

`bmesh` itself is available from outside, but since I don't open blender, there would be no saving options available. How can I do that?

Comment: `bmesh` module only works with blender.

Comment: You can run blender in background through the command line https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html

Comment: `bmesh` module is accessible without requiring blender running, look [this doc link](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_api_reference.html#reference-api-scope). this module is somehow separate from other blender modules.

Comment: yes in order to use it without opening the blender, you have to install it in your system as a python package/module.

Comment: can you `import bmesh` in your python file?

Comment: @Karan yes, that's not the issue ;) I already have that and I can import and use it.
The problem is how to get a usable output from it without opening blender explicitly.

Comment: AFAIK, This module provides access to blenders' bmesh data structures which can't be used outside of blender. https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Modeling/BMesh/Design

Comment: @Karan Nope! first I've used bmesh before! second It is clearly mentioned in [this doc link](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_api_reference.html#reference-api-scope)! third, we are moving away from the issue!

Comment: OK, then provide some example script in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but for anyone who comes across this; use [BlenderProc](https://github.com/DLR-RM/BlenderProc). It allows you to use blender's python api (including bmesh) without ever opening blender. It can be installed as easily as `pip install blenderproc`. The only nuance is that you'll have to use `blenderproc run script.py` instead of `python script.py`, but it works exactly the same way and still runs using your regular python installation. Hope this helps

Comment: I find using "blenderproc run " very hard to debug. How can I run blenderproc scripts without this?